# PaddingValues except bottomPadding in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, padding, edge-to-edge

**Issue**

I'm looking for a way to alter `PaddingValues`, so that they don't include any `BottomPadding`.
My current Implementation looks like this, but here i need to pass `LayoutDirection`, which feels really clumsy.

```
fun PaddingValues.exceptBottomPadding(layoutDirection: LayoutDirection) =
    PaddingValues(
        top = calculateTopPadding(),
        bottom = 0.dp,
        end = calculateEndPadding(layoutDirection),
        start = calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection)
    )
```

I initially had hoped there would be a data-class-like way of altering `PaddingValues`, e.g. `myPadding.copy(bottom = 0.dp)`, but nope, this would have been to easy...

---

**Usecase**

I'm going "edge to edge" with my Material3-Android-App.
For that my `Scaffold` provides my `content` with `PaddingValues` (inclusive `Insets`).

However, my main content scrolling view should also be edge to edge, so i'd like to ignore the bottom part of the `PaddingValues`.
(I'll later re-add it as content padding, but that's easy enough).

Something like:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = { ... },
) { paddingWithInset ->
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingWithInset.exceptBottomPadding()),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = paddingWithInset.calculateBottomPadding())
    ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried just applying the complete `paddingWithInset` as `contentPadding`, but that butchers the [overscrollEffect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4spe6.jpg)

---

**Edit**

The `exceptBottomPadding` can ofc. be made a composable, which allows accessing the `LocalLayoutDirection`. However, this still feels clumsy.

```
@Composable
fun PaddingValues.exceptBottomPadding(): PaddingValues {
    val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current

    return PaddingValues(
        top = calculateTopPadding(),
        bottom = 0.dp,
        end = calculateEndPadding(layoutDirection),
        start = calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a generic extension function:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    fun PaddingValues.copy(
        start: Dp? = null,
        top: Dp? = null,
        end: Dp? = null,
        bottom: Dp? = null
    ): PaddingValues {
        val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
        return PaddingValues(
            start = start ?: this.calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection),
            top = top ?: this.calculateTopPadding(),
            end = end ?: this.calculateEndPadding(layoutDirection),
            bottom = bottom ?: this.calculateBottomPadding(),
        )
    }
```

And I use it like this:

```kotlin
Column(paddingValues = it.copy(bottom = 0.dp))
```